# PostgreSQL Backup With Barman

Tags: server, backup, postgresql

I'm trying to backup my server which i created on PostgreSQL (9.1). While on my normal user i type "su barman", it asks me barman's password, i enter the password. On barman's shell i type "barman list-server" but it returns nothing. My server is on the same computer.

Comment: Did you configure the server in barman's config file? (See the barman manual).

Comment: @CraigRinger what i have to type there?

Comment: Please read http://www.pgbarman.org/documentation/ . If you're still stuck, follow up here.

Comment: @CraigRinger i have red that again and again but i'm newbie and i can't understand what am i supposed to do. So i need easiest way of this for understand what am i doing. (I am an internship)

Comment: OK. So, do you understand PostgreSQL's WAL archiving at all? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html . Understanding that and base backups are key. But really, the barman docs step you through this, so if you're struggling with them you may need to improve your general sysadmin skills first - understanding ssh and private keys, etc. Did you read the **Basic Configuration** heading in the barman docs? Based on that, what did you then do? Please explain what you've already tried, what steps you followed from the docs, where you got stuck.

Comment: @CraigRinger I've red Basic Configuration heading and realised that it doesn't look like mine so i didn't change anything on barman.conf file. I've changed barman's and localhost's passwords. Last week one person told me that barman has no writing permission and gave me a few codes. He asked output of this code: `ls -l /var/log/barman.log`. This was the output: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 barman 1001 0 2014-07-15 10:25 /var/log/barman/barman.log`. Then he said : "type this `chown barman:barman /var/log/barman/barman.log` (I'm assuming there is a barman group on your system) then type `usermod -a -G barman`"

Comment: That's totally unrelated. Are you *extremely* new to UNIX/Linux systems perhaps? (Not meaning that negatively, just trying to understand your level of familiarity/understanding). As for "didn't look like mine" ... I'm assuming you mean that the examples of the default file in the docs were different to what you're running. If so, perhaps *you're on a different barman version*? What version are you running (`barman --version`). How'd you install it and from wherE?

Comment: Yeah i'm using Linux for the first time. The output is `1.1.2`. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and there was no barman on Ubuntu Software Center so i installed barman from here http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/postgresql/lucid-pgdg/main/base/barman .

Comment: Uh. OK, for future reference, extras for PostgreSQL, new PostgreSQL versions, etc, are best obtained from http://apt.postgresql.org/  . There's info on Pg on Ubuntu at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL . You're using an old Barman version. Since you're not committed to anything yet, personally I'd uninstall it and put the current release on instead.